# Question related with the Calculation.(Easy but calculation process complicated.)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Though idea for solving of these problems surely simple, I tried these over and over and Whenever I did it, My answer came out differently for each attempts. :( 
(The Calculation process might be little complicated.)

Please help me.

$Q-1)$

$a+b = \sqrt {2 \sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2}, a-b= \sqrt {3\sqrt2 - \sqrt 3}$

**Find the $a^4 + b^4 + 3a^2b^2$**

$Q-2)$
Let the given right triangle that its perimeter's length is $2a$ and length of the Hypotenuse is  $x$

**Then Find the range of the $x$**

My attempt for the Q1

Since $(a+b)^2 = {2 \sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2}$ and $(a-b)^2 = {3\sqrt2 - \sqrt 3}$

$a^2 + b^2 = {1 \over 2}{(\sqrt3 + 2\sqrt 2)}, ab = {1 \over 4}({3 \sqrt3 - 4\sqrt 2})$

$(a^2 + b^2)^2 + a^2b^2  = {1 \over 16}{(103- 8\sqrt 6)}$ **[$Not$  $10$]**

It seems the the answer is incorrect I thought for the Q1. But the one who suggest this question said the answer like the below.

The Answer)

$Q1)$ $10$

$Q2)$ $2(\sqrt2 - 1)a \le x < a$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to part $1$ is correct.

For part $2$, let the interior angle between the leg and hypotenuse of the right triangle be $\theta$. Clearly, $0<\theta<\pi/2$. The perimeter of the triangle$$x+x\cos\theta+x\sin\theta=2a\implies x=\frac{2a}{1+\cos\theta+\sin\theta}$$For the given range of $\theta$, you have $1<\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt2\sin\left(\frac\pi4+\theta\right)\le\sqrt2$, so you get$$\frac{2a}{1+\sqrt2}\le x<\frac{2a}{1+1}$$

Comment: It should be said that the LHS $\frac{2a}{1+\sqrt{2}}$ (in the last line), when  numerator and denominator are multiplied by $1-\sqrt{2}$ gives the LHS $2a(\sqrt{2}-1)$ found by the OP.